# php Anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function, zend-certification

When I was reading questions for Zend Certified PHP Engineer 5.5 I saw question about anonymous function  but I need to explan how it work.

```
function z($x)
{
    return function($y) use ($x)
    {
        return str_repeat( $y , $x );
    };
}

$a = z(2);
$b = z(3);

echo $a(3).$b(2);
```

The output for this code is:

```
33222
```

But in function header there is only `$x` parameter from where `$y` got there value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `z` creates and returns a new function, but an anonymous one. That new function is defined so that it has one argument - `$y`. However, this anonymous function also uses argument `$x` from a function `z`.

To make it simple, function `z` basically creates a function which can repeat any string, but a fixed number of times. The number of times a string is repeated is determined by the value of argument `$x` in `z`.

So, calling `z(2)` creates a new function which is functionally equivalent to writing

```
function repeat_two_times($y) {
    return str_repeat($y, 2);
}
```

In you example, hard coded value 2 is determined by the value of $x.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). The principle displayed by the example can be quite useful for creating [partial functions](http://blog.justinpoliey.com/partial-function-application-in-php.html) like add5, inc10, ...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you initialize function z:

```
$a = z(2);
```

`$x` in the example is set to 2, so the returned function (anonymous function, also called closure) can now be read as (because `$x` is used):

```
$a = function($y) {
    return str_repeat($y, 2);
}
```

When invoking this function:

```
echo $a(3);
```

You are supplying this return function with the parameter 3 (`$y`).

The output is: `33`

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous functions are also known as `Closures`.

You ask where `$y` gets its value. The code example is difficult to decipher because you use 2s and 3s everywhere. Things would be clearer if your last lines were

```
$a = z(2);
$b = z(3);
echo $a('A').$b('B');
```

That would result in:

```
AABBB
```

But let's follow your code. Notice that there are two related function calls

```
 $a = z(2);
```

and

```
 echo $a(3);
```

calling function `z()` with argument 2 returns a function (that is assigned name `$a`) where line

```
 return str_repeat($y, $x);
```

is in reality :

```
 return str_repeat($y, 2);
```

now, you call that function `$a()` with argument 3. That 3 (value of `$y`) is repeated two times

The same analysis applies to the other related function calls:

```
 $b = z(3);
 ...
 echo ... $b(2);
```

But in this case 2 is repeated 3 times

Answer (score 0):

```
 function z($x)
  {
    return function($y) use ($x)
    {
        return str_repeat( $y , $x );
    };
  }

  $a = z(2);// here you are setting value of x by 2
  $b = z(3);// here you are setting value of x by 3
echo $a(3).$b(2);// here $a(3) 3 is value of y so it becomes str_repeat( 3 , 2 ); which is 33
```